# SherlockFragmentActivity with SherlockListFragment

Tags: actionbarsherlock

I have 3 tabs and all of them has lists inside(different ones of course). When i click on tab I see the proper result(result which i would like to get).

I know how to get the clicked item info and make request to database about that item and get result and create new intent and put that result in it as a extra. BUT i don't know how I can display my result inside the same fragment without creating new intent. Because when i create new intent and show result in new intent my tabs obviously disappears, but i need them always to be there.

My main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity
{
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
      actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

      actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
      Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
                .setText("Dictionary")
                .setTabListener(new DictionaryFragment())
                .setIcon(R.drawable.android);

      actionBar.addTab(tab);

      tab = actionBar.newTab()
                .setText("Play")
                .setTabListener(new PlayFragment())
                .setIcon(R.drawable.apple);

      actionBar.addTab(tab);

      tab = actionBar.newTab()
            .setText("Manage")
            .setTabListener(new ManageFragment())
            .setIcon(R.drawable.apple);

      actionBar.addTab(tab);
  }
}
```

One of my fragments:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{   
  built_in_DB_setup dbOpenHelper = new built_in_DB_setup(getActivity().getBaseContext(), DB_NAME);
  database = dbOpenHelper.openDataBase();
  fillFreinds();
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new
  ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, friends);
  setListAdapter(adapter);
  return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
```

And here is the item click listener inside this class

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id); 
    String a=getData(((TextView) v).getText().toString()); 
    Intent i = new Intent("com.example.fragmenttest.VIEWWORD"); 
    i.putExtra("result", a); 
    startActivity(i); 
}
```

Ones I have String a which i have got from onListItemClick how can I replace current Tab data with this string?